# Alignment issue with <td> tags

Tags: html, css

I have an alignment issue for aligning the contentlink with asp:ImageButton btnAdd and btnArrow. Also the markup is nested table.  can it be simplified?

Entire markup

```
 <table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><table>
          <tr>
            <td><asp:Image ID="ModelImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>'></asp:Image></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      <td><table>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:0.5em"><asp:Label ID="ModelLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DocumentName") %>' Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;padding-bottom:1em;padding-left:0.5em;"><asp:Label ID="txtText1" runat="server" Text="The May edition of News Brief contains seven newsworthy articles"></asp:Label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:0.5em"><asp:Label ID="txtText2" runat="server" Text="Suggested Subject Line: The May 2014 News Brief has arrived!"></asp:Label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;padding-left:0.5em;"><asp:LinkButton Text="> Content Link 1" runat="server" style="padding-top:10px"></asp:LinkButton>
              <asp:ImageButton ID="btnArrow" runat="server" OnClick="btnArrow_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/DownloadIcon2.png" ToolTip="Download Item" style="padding-top:10px;" />
              <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/DownloadIcon1.png" ToolTip="Add to Download List" style="padding-top:10px" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way to simplify the  tags?

Comment: You have missed closing your <table> tag in your second of the main table check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your markup, Instead of using nested table, you can use `rowspan` to achieve the same styling. Anyway I would suggest you should not use tables nowadays.

Also i have removed your inline styles and apply it through CSS which is good practice.

**HTML**

```
  <table class="newformat">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td rowspan="5"><asp:Image ID="ModelImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>'></asp:Image></td>
      </tr>       
      <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="ModelLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DocumentName") %>' Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="PaddBott"><asp:Label ID="txtText1" runat="server" Text="The May edition of News Brief contains seven newsworthy articles"></asp:Label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="txtText2" runat="server" Text="Suggested Subject Line: The May 2014 News Brief has arrived!"></asp:Label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td nowrap><asp:LinkButton Text="Content Link 1" runat="server" style="padding-top:10px"></asp:LinkButton>
          <asp:ImageButton ID="btnArrow" runat="server" OnClick="btnArrow_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/DownloadIcon2.png" ToolTip="Download Item" style="padding-top:10px;" />
          <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/DownloadIcon1.png" ToolTip="Add to Download List" style="padding-top:10px" />
        </td>
      </tr>       
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

**CSS**

```
table.newformat{padding:0;border:0;border-collapse:collapse;}
table.newformat td{padding-left:0.5em;}
.PaddBott{padding-bottom:1em;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a grid-based system like the following:

bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/

zurb foundation grid: http://foundation.zurb.com/grid.html

You would use rows and columns instead of tables

Hope this helps.